vite build generating duplicate interfaces in index.d.ts
I have a simple vite reactjs component library with the following interface that is imported and used from other pages.
src/dtos/dtos.ts
export interface User {}

export interface Document {}

src/contexts/mainContext.ts
import { User, Document } from "../dtos/dtos";

and other areas as well.
now in src/index.ts I did exports:
export type { User, Document } from "./dtos/dtos";

export { mainContext } from "./contexts/MainContexts"

when I do vite build now, in dist/index.d.ts, I see User, User_2, Document and Document_2. it does generate es and umd files in /dist.
What could be causing the duplicate?
tsconfig.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "ES2020",
      "useDefineForClassFields": true,
      "lib": ["ES2020"],
      "module": "ESNext",
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "declaration": true,
      //"declarationMap": true,
  
      "paths": {
        "@dtos/*": ["./src/dtos/*"],
        "@contexts/*": ["./src/contexts/*"],
      },
  
      /* Bundler mode */
      "moduleResolution": "bundler",
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
      "isolatedModules": true,
      "noEmit": false,
      "jsx": "react-jsx",
      "noImplicitAny": false,
      /* Linting */
      "strict": true,
      "noUnusedLocals": true,
      "noUnusedParameters": true,
      "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true
    },
    "include": ["src", "dist/index.d.ts"],
    "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
  }

tsconfig.node.json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "composite": true,
      "module": "ESNext",
      "moduleResolution": "Node",
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
      "resolveJsonModule": true,
    },
    "include": ["vite.config.ts","package.json"],
}

vite.config.ts
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'
import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts'
import tsconfigPaths from "vite-tsconfig-paths";
import * as packageJson from './package.json'
import { resolve } from "node:path";


// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(), 
    tsconfigPaths(),
    dts({
      insertTypesEntry: true,
      rollupTypes: true,
    }),
  
  ],

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@dtos/*": "./src/dtos/*",
      "@contexts/*": "./src/contexts/*",
    },
  },
  build: {
    lib: {
      entry: resolve('src', 'index.ts'),
      name: 'App',
      formats: ['es', 'umd'],
      fileName: (format) => `app.${format}.js`,
    },
    rollupOptions: {
      external: [...Object.keys(packageJson.peerDependencies), 
        "react"],
        output: {
          globals: {
            react: "React"
          },
        },
    },
    sourcemap: true,
    emptyOutDir: true,
  },
})

package.json

{
  "name": "@saus/app",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext ts,tsx --report-unused-disable-directives --max-warnings 0",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "test": "jest --config=jest.config.cjs"
  },
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "import": "./dist/app.es.js",
      "require": "./dist/app.umd.js",
      "types": "./dist/index.d.ts"
    },
    "./dist/index.d.ts": "./dist/index.d.ts"
  },
  "main": "./dist/app.umd.js",
  "module": "./dist/app.es.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^18.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}



Can't tell why but remove the aliases in vite and ts configs helped...
